# JPanel not updating when my ArrayList of GamePieces changes

Tags: arraylist, jpanel

I have a simple game that is in progress.  As of right now all I want to do is click the green button and have the fifth and third pieces switch places.  The paintComponent is called after the swap in the arraylist is made, but the JPanel is not refreshed to show these changes.  When i am running my application I am choosing 4 for the pieces for each side.  Thus, the inner green and black pieces should change place.  Please help.

Number1.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Container;

public class Number1 {

private static JButton greenButton,blackButton,newGameButton,inputButton;
private static JTextFieldNumber inputField;
static MyActionListen actionListen;
static Number1 myGame;
static JFrame myDialog,myFrame;
static DrawGamePieces gamePanel;
public int piecesPerSide = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    myGame = new Number1();
    actionListen = new MyActionListen();
    myGame.getStartingTokensValue();

    System.out.println(Color.WHITE.toString());

}

private void makeComponents()  
{
    //Setting up the green button click
    greenButton = new JButton("Green");
    greenButton.setBounds(40, 0 , 100, 40);
    greenButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    greenButton.addActionListener(actionListen);
    //Setting up the black button click
    blackButton = new JButton("Black");
    blackButton.setBounds(greenButton.getLocation().x + greenButton.getWidth() + 10
                , 0 , 100, 40);
    blackButton.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    blackButton.addActionListener(actionListen);
    //Setting up the new game button click
    newGameButton = new JButton("New Game");
    newGameButton.setBounds(blackButton.getLocation().x + blackButton.getWidth() + 10
                , 0 , 100, 40);
    newGameButton.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    newGameButton.addActionListener(actionListen);

    //init gamePanel
    gamePanel = new DrawGamePieces(myGame.piecesPerSide,myFrame.getSize().width, myFrame.getSize().height - 40);
    gamePanel.setLocation(0, 40);
    gamePanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

}

private  void makeGameFrame()
{
    myFrame = new JFrame();
    if(myGame.piecesPerSide <= 10)  myFrame.setSize(400, 250);
    else                            myFrame.setSize(600, 250);

    myFrame.setLocation(300, 100);
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  //sets the default close method
    myFrame.setTitle("Solitary Game"); //sets the title of the window
    Container mainFrameContents = myFrame.getContentPane();//get the content pane to add components to
    mainFrameContents.setLayout(null); //allowed setBounds on components to work properly
    mainFrameContents.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

    myGame.makeComponents(); //makes all the sub components

    //adds all subcomponents to content pane
    mainFrameContents.add(greenButton); 
    mainFrameContents.add(blackButton); 
    mainFrameContents.add(newGameButton); 
    mainFrameContents.add(gamePanel);
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
}

//gets the starting value of the tokens for the game
private void getStartingTokensValue()
{
    myDialog = new JFrame("New Game Information");
    myDialog.setSize(450, 150);
    myDialog.setLocation(300, 100);
    myDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  //sets the default close method
    JLabel l = new JLabel("Please Enter the Number of Pieces for each side of the game (1-20)");
    l.setBounds((myDialog.getSize().width - 420)/2, 0, 420, 30);
    inputField = new JTextFieldNumber("0123456789");
    inputField.setBounds((myDialog.getSize().width - 100)/2, 35, 100, 30);
    inputButton = new JButton("Submit");
    inputButton.setBounds((myDialog.getSize().width - 100)/2, 75, 100, 30);
    inputButton.addActionListener(actionListen);
    myDialog.setLayout(null);
    myDialog.add(inputButton);
    myDialog.add(l);
    myDialog.add(inputField);
    myDialog.setVisible(true);

}




private static class MyActionListen implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ap)
    {

        if(ap.getSource().equals(greenButton)){
            System.out.println("Requet to green move");
            gamePanel.greenMove();

        }else if(ap.getSource().equals(blackButton)){
            System.out.println("Requet to black move");

        }else if(ap.getSource().equals(newGameButton)){
                System.out.println("Requet to start new game");


        }else if(ap.getSource().equals(inputButton)){
            if(inputField.getText().length()>0)
            {
                myGame.piecesPerSide = Integer.parseInt(inputField.getText());
                if(inputField.checkAllCharacters() && (myGame.piecesPerSide <= 20) && (myGame.piecesPerSide>0))
                {
                    myDialog.dispose();
                    myGame.makeGameFrame();
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(inputField, "Please only type in an integer from 1 to 20");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

DrawGamePieces.java

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import javax.swing.JPanel;


    public class DrawGamePieces extends JPanel{

private ArrayList<GamePiece> gamePieces;
private int ballR = 15;

//paint or repaints the board
protected void paintComponent( Graphics g ){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    System.out.println("paint components called");

    for(int i=0;i<gamePieces.size();i++)
    {
        GamePiece temp = gamePieces.get(i);
        g.setColor(temp.getColor());
        g.fillOval(temp.x,temp.y,ballR,ballR);
    }
}

//init the game board
public DrawGamePieces(int piecesPerSide,int aWidth,int aHeight){
    gamePieces = new ArrayList<GamePiece>();
    super.setSize(aWidth, aHeight);
    //space between wall and first piece
    int blankSpace = (int)((aWidth - (ballR)*(2*piecesPerSide+1))/2);

    //initalized the pieces in the arraylist
    for(int i=0;i<(2*piecesPerSide+1);i++)
    {
        GamePiece temp = null;
        if(i == 0)                          temp = new GamePiece(blankSpace,80,Color.GREEN);
        if((i < piecesPerSide) && (i != 0)) temp = new GamePiece(ballR+gamePieces.get(i-1).x,80,Color.GREEN);
        if(i > piecesPerSide)               temp = new GamePiece(ballR+gamePieces.get(i-1).x,80,Color.BLACK);
        if(i == piecesPerSide)              temp = new GamePiece(ballR+gamePieces.get(i-1).x,80,Color.YELLOW);
        gamePieces.add(temp);
    }
}

public void greenMove(){
    GamePiece temp = gamePieces.get(5);
    gamePieces.set(5, gamePieces.get(3));
    gamePieces.set(3, temp);

    repaint();
}

public void blackMove(){
    GamePiece temp = gamePieces.get(5);
    gamePieces.set(5, gamePieces.get(3));
    gamePieces.set(3, temp);
}

private int pieceMoveable(Color c){
    int index = -1, start = 0, end = 0,change = 0;
    if(c == Color.GREEN){
        start = 0;
        end = gamePieces.size();
        change = 1;
    }else{
        start = gamePieces.size();
        end = 0;
        change = -1;
    }
    for (int i=start;i<end;i= i+change){
        //if(change = )

    }


    return index;
}

    }
```

GamePiece.java

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Point;

    public class GamePiece extends Point{

private Color pieceColor;

public Color getColor(){
    return pieceColor;
}

public GamePiece()
{
    super();
}

public GamePiece(int x,int y,Color aColor)
{
    super(x,y);
    pieceColor = aColor;
}

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add more `printf`s to get more information about what is happening. Inside `greenMove()`, print out the contents of the `ArrayList` after you do the swap. Do the same inside `paintComponent`. In the `printf`, also indicate where these debugging messages are being printed from. In the loop in `printComponent`, print out the location and color of each piece as you draw it.

Comment: Thank you.  I was swaping the order in which the balls were paint not the order of the balls.

Comment: I Have been trying to upvote you answer but it says that I need more reputation points.  I am new to this site, so they will not let me upvote.  Sorry.